# Would a site on the interdisciplinary topic of climate change in Stack Exchange be supported?

Tags: discussion, scope

The topic of climate change is an exemplary case of an interdisciplinary topic.
There is not one single scientific discipline of science working on it, but a wide spectrum.
It primarily includes meteorologists, physicists, sociologists, psychologists, statisticians and researchers of media studies.

Stack Exchange sites exist for individual sciences, but also for topics like bicycles and cooking. While usually not regarded as a science, these topics could be seen as scientific in an interdisciplinary way. So I think it is as a topic suitable for Stack Exchange.

Should a Stack Exchange site about climate change exist at all, and are there members of this site interested in it?

(You may want to have a look at a proposal for such a site: [Climate Change](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123397/climate-change).)

Comment: It's covered by Earth Sciences SE.  See [the answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334872/369105) on main meta asking basically the same thing

Comment: I don't think just because you are asking about a different SE site that users of Physics SE might be interested in means this question belongs on Physics Meta.

Comment: It seems like we already have stacks dedicated to the topics you want to look at, such as Earth Sciences and Politics.  It seems like it would make the most sense to ask the relevant questions on the relevant stacks, instead of making a new one to try to mix the topics together.  It seems like it would just dilute the answer quality; since users may not be familiar with the political or scientific side.

Comment: @JMac The point is that many questions are either related to more than one discipline, but not in a distinct way. It can even be unclear which disciplines are involved. The very simple question why people not understand the basics of the greenhouse effect is for me, as a German, outright irritating. It involves psychology, of course, but certainly more. Sociology, possibly political sciences (though I do not see how). It is indeed interdisciplinary, involving questions that are not clearly in the field of specific disciplines.

Comment: How is this venue, at all, the right place for this discussion?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Because it is a topic that is well defined, and inherently interdisciplinary. It is not that the questions belong to multiple different disciplines, but single questions are spanning multiple disciplines. A physicist who is interested in the topic is a physicist as in the scope of this site. I assume that a physicist subscribing to a potential site about climate change would typically subscribe to this site also. That means, the people that may potentially be interested in this, as physicists, are almost exactly the members here.

Comment: But you aren't asking about the Physics SE site here. You are asking about a different site. This site is for questions about the Physics SE site, not other sites that are related or would attract similar users. There are other sites recommended to you that would be better for this question.

Comment: Beside the Earth Science SE, you can also try the [Skeptics SE](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com), if it is more about validity testing. Also the Law SE and Politics SE might have some on-topic part.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, this has [already been explored in the Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334871/would-it-be-possible-to-create-a-site-on-climate-change/334872#334872). There already is a site that incorporates the bulk of what you're proposing, and ─ as you [just found out](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123397/climate-change) ─ the MSE suggestion that your site proposal would get closed as a duplicate of the existing Earth Science site was dead accurate.

You might want to argue that the existing Earth Science site does not fully cover all the topics that you might want it to. **This meta is not the venue for that discussion, which has nothing to do with the Physics Stack Exchange site.**

On the other hand, if you have a beta site or a site proposal on Area 51 that you want to advertise to users of this site, the correct place to do it is the thread [Consider supporting proposals of other SE science sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites) on this meta.