# Beta Site: Materials Modeling

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

If this is off-topic, I can take it down, but Phys Meta has generally been receptive to [promoting other science proposals/sites](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites) in the network.

[Materials Modeling SE](https://materials.stackexchange.com/) entered private beta at the end of April. The site aims to address research level questions about both the theory, methods, and implementation behind modeling systems ranging from molecules and proteins, to nanoparticles/sheets/tubes and polymers, to crystals and topological materials. Users come from a wide range of disciplines (chemistry, material science, computational science, drug design) and use a wide range of different modeling frameworks (molecular dynamics, electronic structure theory, Markov models/statistical mechanics, fluid dynamics, machine learning).

The site is coming up on the decision whether it can move to public beta and we would really appreciate your support. If any of the topics above interest you, or you think there is something in the realm of material simulation/computation that could be addressed well there, please consider joining the site and asking/answering/upvoting some questions. We think this site could have real value to the scientific community and it has already attracted a healthy amount of attention from experts across different fields, but we need the SE network clearly sees that value to ensure that the site is maintained.

For more discussion of the scope of the site: [Topics](https://materials.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here), [Distinguishing Features](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29831/how-can-this-proposal-be-clearly-distinguished-from-chemistry-physics-computat/29832#29832)

Comment: The site has officially moved to Public Beta! Thank you for the support!

Comment: Re *"...Phys Meta has generally been receptive"*: A later example [is *Bioacoustics*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14140/new-bioacoustics-se-site-may-be-of-interest-to-you).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this proposal for a new site is very interesting. I hope don't disturb with this answer (really I'm not interested in the site, I'm just an amateur mathematician, but your idea and yours colleagues to create this site seems to me very good).

A material that is fascinating for me is the known as sepiolite (I know just the more simple uses of this material, but I'm curious, from a divulgative point of view, about other important applications see the last phrase and reference from the Wikipedia [*Sepiolite*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepiolite) from the section *Other uses and substitutes*).

This is just to say that good luck with your project, and add my contribution commenting here about that sepiolite seems interesting for me. Feel free to comment if this answer isn't suitable or useful, I hope don't disturb. Thanks you very much, and good day.

Yesterday I remembered this post because I heard on the radio news about a new metamaterial. I think that it is worthy to edit my answer again. The material is known as *Copper-Squarate*. The article [1] is for the attention of the professor who edited the original post and for the professor of Physics Stack Exchange (I hope don't bother editing this) after my welcome for the site that was promoted **Matter Modeling Stack Exchange.**

### References:

[1] Francisco Colmenero, Álvaro Lobato and Vicente Timón, *Compressing the Channels in the Crystal Structure of Copper Squarate Metal-Organic Framework*, Solids 2022, 3(2), pages 374-384.

Comment: In last weeks I was also interested in some documentaries that I've seen or in videos. Motivated from the documentary with title *The Origami Code*, by François-Xavier Vives (2015), I was searching in arXiv about preprints related to applications of origami and I found **1904.06409**, that I think that corresponds to reference *Origami launcher*, Emergent Scientist **3**, 5 (2019) by Oryna Ivashtenko, Polina Kofman, Oleksiy Golubov and Zakhar Maizelis. And I've seen videos (in Spanish) from YouTube by Pablo Jarillo-Herrero (I add as reference that Wikipedia has an article for this professor).

Comment: Happy to have your support! If you do wind up having any specific question about, for example uses/properties of sepiolite, you can always post a question there. The site is also pretty heavily about computation/theory, so a question that bridges a gap between pure math and materials would also be interesting.

Comment: I had ideas about the sepiolite, but I prefer don't evoke these because I'm not a scientific. Feel free to think and investigate about the uses or applications of this material. Many thanks again, and good luck @Tyberius

Comment: The podcast *Escuarato de cobre*  is in Spanish Language, A golpe de bit of **RADIO 5**  (published 28/09/2022).

Comment: I found a channel of YouTube that might be interesting, the channel **The Clay Minerals Society** (see Wikipedia), this includes a video *Binding of DNA to the natural clay silicate sepiolite: Applications in biotechnology and perspective* edited at 30 nov 2021 that seems very interesting. I hope don't bother @Tyberius