# New bioacoustics SE site may be of interest to you

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The **Bioacoustics Stack Exchange** has reached the Beta stage and is LIVE! It is also in a critical stage, and we need your help to keep it alive.  Bioacoustics uses methods from physics, signal processing, biology and more, so you may be interested to join!

We have only 2 weeks to prove we have the community to support the site! Please help as you can!

How can you help?

- **JOIN**: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/
  **VISIT**: Make it a habit to check in on the site regularly. We need >>500 visits per day!
- **VOTE**: We need to show participation! Vote on all good Q/A
- **ASK**: Have a new bioacoustics-related question? What about your older questions? You can even ask/answer your own question! These questions will be archived for future use, so ALL good questions are welcome! We need >> 10 questions per day!
- **ANSWER**: Have an answer to one of the questions, or additional information? Share your expertise where you can! Is there a question you are often asked? You can pair up with someone to ask/answer it again to be archived! If someone asks you a question-- tell them you will answer it on the Stack Exchange! We need ~2.5 answers per question.
- **INVITE & SHARE**: Invite others to join! Share on social media, with your collaborators, etc.!
- **DISCUSS** the proposed site at the Meta page to suggest features and get help

**DO NOT DELAY!** Participate today and every day that you can. We know our community can support a site, but it takes time to create this habit. Unfortunately, this proposal has a deadline and we need ALL the help we can get, as often as possible!

**Why do we need a SE site in Bioacoustics?**

Because it is one of the fastest growing fields in both marine and terrestrial science. It gives us a unique opportunity to observe animal behavior and track populations’ distribution non-invasively.  Additionally, if done correctly, it can be easier and cheaper to collect data than traditional survey techniques. Most bioacoustic equipment is several thousand dollars/euros, sure, but that equipment can be left unattended, collecting data, ranging from weeks to months. This makes it more accessible to a larger group of researchers, and smaller companies are cropping up to make the startup costs even cheaper. However, analyzing that data can be a headache. You can find yourself with terabytes of acoustic data, and not know what to do with it.

**But I’m not an expert, so this doesn’t sound like it’s for me.**

We need folks from ALL walks of life! We need experts, yes, but we also need enthusiastics, students, related professionals, and folks that are just curious.  We need folks asking questions that those of us conducting research wouldn’t think to ask in addition to the folks that can answer those questions.

So please, check it out, and join us! And if you have questions, you can reach out to bioacousticsse@gmail.com or shannon.rankin@noaa.gov.

**EXEMPLE QUESTIONS WHICH INVOLVE PHYSICS**

- [Why are high frequency sounds absorbed more than low frequency sound?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/425/why-are-high-frequency-sounds-absorbed-more-than-low-frequency-sound)
- [Microphone calibration stability?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/403/microphone-calibration-stability)
- [Is it possible to estimate particle velocity from a pressure microphone?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/155/is-it-possible-to-estimate-particle-velocity-from-a-pressure-microphone)
- [Modeling acoustic propagation for underwater environment](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/95/modeling-acoustic-propagation-for-underwater-environment)
- [Simulating sound propagation to test analysis workflows](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/67/simulating-sound-propagation-to-test-analysis-workflows)
- [How to compensate for atmospheric attenuation of a broadband sound?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/49/how-to-compensate-for-atmospheric-attenuation-of-a-broadband-sound)
- [Why does sound from ships propagate better in deep water than in shallow water?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/25/why-does-sound-from-ships-propagate-better-in-deep-water-than-in-shallow-water)
- [Can we measure distance from the animal harmonic calls?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/3/can-we-measure-distance-from-the-animal-harmonic-calls)
- [Distant impact on sea mammals of propagated sound wave of underwater nuclear tests](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/questions/522/distant-impact-on-sea-mammals-of-propagated-sound-wave-of-underwater-nuclear-tes)

Comment: Why is this a post on our meta? How is this site related to physics? Is there overlap in scope, i.e. are there questions that would be on-topic here that would be on-topic there, too? Is there strong overlap in potential audiences? I'm not in principle against advertising other sites on our meta, but I'd like to see at least *some* explanation for why this might be of interest to users of physics.SE.

Comment: @ACuriousMind To my reading the overlap is pretty obvious, and the case for advertising it here goes without saying.

Comment: Forget all other reasons than [the rare and shiny badge](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/30/beta) at the end of it!

Comment: @ACuriousMind I posted here as I expect that some people here will have an interest: bioacoustics combines biology and acoustics which is a branch of physics

Comment: @EmilioPisanty some will certainly be interested, but the current questions appear to have limited overlap with physics. Maybe the site will increase this overlap - it’s still early - and I wish them best of luck but it does look like a bit of a short in the dark.  It *would* be better if the issues raised by ACuriousMind were addressed by the OP.

Comment: Maybe the OP could link some questions which they think would be of interest to this community…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Good idea, thanks. I've just added some current questions that could be of interest to physicists. We welcome any physics-oriented questions that are specifics to animal acoustic communication

Comment: There's no way “The site went into private beta on 2/20/2018 and will undergo evaluation by the Community Team within 5 weeks of that date. At that point, it will either be moved into public beta or closed down.” is accurate.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I would trust the numbers from the [Area51 proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics) more.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm curious to know where you read that the site went into private beta in 2018, as we started 2 weeks ago :-).

Comment: @Noil On the pre-joining sign-up page, which I think is only for users who haven't committed.

Comment: From this [thread](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20966/minimum-activity-requirements-for-area-51/28468#28468), it seems that there was a Bioacoustics proposal some years ago that did not make it ([here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119914/bioacoustics)).
The live one I am talking about is [https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698) and we hope to keep it as healthy as it has been since being launched.